# PHP - If condition not working

Tags: php, if-statement, syntax

The if condition below is not working

```
if(!strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'iPhone') && $task != "view"){

    //do something

}
```

What I am trying to say here is that if not iPhone and if $task not equal to view, then do something.

Currently $task is equal to view but I am not on an iPhone, so I should see the (do something code) I have.

What's wrong with my condition?

Comment: what is the `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` and `$task` data? for me it is working fine

Comment: Check values of `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` and `$task` before `if` then you might get an idea, otherwise you'll have to post full code

Comment: `var_dump()` your variables.

Comment: $task is equal to view then this will not be true `$task != "view"`

Answer (score 2):

> Currently $task is equal to view but I am not on an iPhone, so I should see the (do something code) I have.

This means you want want prevent "iPhone" **or** "view" but what you implement is preventing "iPhone" **and** "view". Try this:

```
if(!strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'iPhone') or $task != "view"){

    //do something

}
```

Comment: Sidenote: `||` has precedence over `OR`